# I can not connect sql server 2014 remote using static ip internet But when i connect sql server using my mobile internet it is working

Tags: sql-server

[image]Blocked firewall

Enabled TCP/IP protocol  port 1433

Sql server running

Local server working fine

Issue only in static ip internet Please help me how can fix this issue

Comment: I can see that you are making edits to your question, so I'll prefer to wait before replying. However, you'll have to add more info for someone to guide as there can be dozens of things blocking it. Just guessing wild - Have you opened port and done port forwarding on your router/modem?

Comment: how can i check

Comment: I'm unable to provide exact steps because it depends on your router/modem. For exacts steps and screenshots,you can Google with your modem/router model number etc. In summary, this is how you do it-type the router ip in the browser (try your luck with 192.168.1.1 o r192.168.1.254) 
Enter the user Id and password (should be on the back of the modem)
Go to 'Port Forwarding'
You'll then have to forward the incoming port to the port of your sql server
Now when I have said it, I'll also put the disclaimer here-You must know what you're doing else you might expose the machine to security issues.

Comment: But if you want to access a port number of your machine over Internet, you'll have to open that on your router first to allow the traffic to enter into your local network. Else your router will simply reject it.

Comment: Hi @RintoAntony, have you solved this problem?? I am facing the same issue right now.